# SOAP UI sending attachment which contains Cyrillic characters

Tags: web-services, character-encoding, soapui, mtom, cyrillic

I am working on an application allowing user to upload XML file to server through a web service. Files are sent as attachment. I am using MTOM. I was able to send and receive file.
The problem is that my XML file contains Cyrillic letter. When I print XML on server side all Cyrillic letters changed into something like "=D0=9A=D0=95=D0=9D=D0=96=D0=90=D0==9B=D0=98=D0=9D=D0=9E=D0=92=D0=90". At first I thought that  java code was wrong and I used wrong encoding when reading XML file attachment on server side.  To test the web service I use SOAPUI. I started looking at the request and found that even before request containing the file was sent, SOAPUI already "messed up" the characters in the attachment. 
[image: raw request in SOAPUI]

How should I set the SOAPUI setting to send proper request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mmm anyways I was using old version of soapui. After I got the latest one, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Set the Encoding property in you test request to UTF-8.

Comment: yep. This step is also necessary